# Teradata FastExport Script - cannot get it to run - The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: database, teradata

I am brand new to teradata. I wrote a fastexport script to take some data from a db and export it to some excel files.
The script is all good. I just can't run it!

I am running the cmd `fexp < C:\Documents\ScriptName` (that is not the actual path)

Where ScriptName is a .txt file containing the script.

I get the error:

> "The system cannot find the file specified"

I have tried changing the location of the file and such but always get the same error.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The correct command is:

fexp < "C:\Path to file\ScriptName.txt"